# Using the variable on range scope `x` in function literal (scopelint)

Tags: unit-testing, go

```
func TestGetUID(t *testing.T) {
    namespace := "lkfm"
    expecteduid := "fake_uid"
    var tests = []struct {
        description string
        expected    string
        namespace   string
        objs        []runtime.Object
    }{
        {"PositiveScenario", expecteduid, namespace, []runtime.Object{simpleNamespace(namespace)}},
    }

    for _, x := range tests {
        t.Run(x.description, func(t *testing.T) {
            client := fake.NewSimpleClientset(x.objs...)
            actual := getUID(client, x.namespace)
            assert.Equal(t, x.expected, actual)
        })
    }
}
```

Lint give me some problem on :

- client := fake.NewSimpleClientset(x.objs...)
- actual := getUID(client, x.namespace)
- assert.Equal(t, x.expected, actual)

and it reports this error : "**Using the variable on range scope `x` in function literal (scopelint)**"

Comment: You can make `lint` happy by creating a copy of `x` inside the loop, i.e. add `x := x` just above `t.Run(...`.

Comment: See https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines.

Comment: Hi @mkopriva, could you explain to me the reason ?

Comment: @GiuseppePercuoco well the reason is the same as explained by icza. When you do `x := x` inside the loop, you are declaring a *new* variable `x` and assigning it the value of the old variable `x`. The linter detects that and knows that any code inside the loop after that that references `x` is referencing the new `x` which is local to the current iteration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`x` is the loop variable which is reused in each iteration. And you create a function literal which you pass to `t.Run()`. The compiler does not know (does not have guarantee) whether the created and passed function literal is not called after `t.Run()` returns, in which case the function literal would refer to the loop variable which will be overwritten with the value of the next iteration. This is rarely–if ever–the intention. It's often the source of nasty bugs, even data race if the function literal is executed concurrently in another gorotuine.

So `go vet` warns about such uses.

Often the solution is to pass the *value* of the loop variable to the function literal as an argument, or create a copy of the loop variable and refer to the copy. Since the signature of your function literal is fixed (you can't change it), create a copy of the variable, e.g.:

```
x2 := x
```

And refer to `x2` inside the function literal. This will make `go vet` happy.

Also, since the intention of making a copy is clear, you may use the same name, e.g. `x := x`, which copy will shadow the loop variable. After the above short variable declaration, the identifier `x` will refer to the local copy (and not the loop variable). In general this may cause confusion, but here the intention is clear and acceptable.